# How to properly use Scala Play Anorm and Option[String] to insert NULL SQL

Tags: mysql, scala, sql-insert, anorm

What is the proper way to insert Option[String] when it is None? The below code inserts an empty string, which is not the same as NULL in mysql.

Is the only way to build the SQL string beforehand based on the content of partnerCode? Sigh...Anorm...

```
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>

  val id: Option[Long] = SQL(
    """
    INSERT INTO users (email, partner_code, is_active, created, pass) VALUES ({email}, {partnerCode}, 0, NOW(), {pass})
    """
  ).on(
    'email -> user.email,
    'partnerCode -> user.partnerCode.getOrElse(""),  // FIXME: how to use NULL keyword instead of empty string? Is Anorm just this dumb?
    'pass -> hashPassword(user.password.get)
  ).executeInsert()

  id.get

}
```

Comment: 'partnerCode -> user.partnerCode.getOrElse(null) seems to work fine, but that seems clunky. Guess partnerCode really shouldn't be optional.

Answer (score 4):

`None` should actually work fine if you import `anorm._` or `anorm.toParameterValue`:

```
'partnerCode -> user.partnerCode
```

Comment: Using `SQL"""` with interpolation, along with `import anorm._`, did not work for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489039/using-optionbigdecimal-with-anorm.