# Using `Option[BigDecimal]` with Anorm?

Tags: scala, anorm

Given:

## build.sbt

```
$cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "anorm_2.11" % "2.5.1"
```

## REPL

```
import anorm._

val x: Option[BigDecimal] = Some(42)
val none: Option[BigDecimal] = None

// invoke Oracle function `f`
scala> SQL""" select f(#$x) from dual """.sql.statement
res0: String = " select f(Some(42)) from dual "

scala> SQL""" select f(#$none) from dual """.sql.statement
res1: String = " select f(None) from dual "
```

I'd like for `res0` to equal: `select f(42) from dual`, and for `res1` to equal `select f(NULL) from dual`.

How can I modify my `SQL` code to fit my desired results?

I imported `anorm._`, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/22531320/409976, however, it did not give my desired result.

Comment: What is `f(..)` ? `.sql` returns statement without parameters, so I don't even see how the above can simple.

Comment: `f` is an Oracle function that I'm trying to invoke. Well, I'm passing parameters via interpolation, i.e. literally with `#$`.

Comment: Using SQL interpolation, parameter values must be passed using `$` but not `#$` (which is for compat with plain String interpolation, not recommanded for parameter as it would expose SQL injection possibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$` interpolation, just use `SQL""" select f($x) from dual """`.

You *can* do it with `#$`, but you certainly shouldn't (`#$` should only be used when you can't do what you want with `$`: e.g. for interpolating table or column names):

```
def invokeF(x: Option[BigDecimal]) = {
  val xInSql = x.fold("NULL")(_.toString) // can be inlined to get even less readable
  SQL""" select f(#$xInSql) from dual """
}
```

Comment: Using `orNull` on `Option` of JDBC parameter is generally not a good idea

Comment: Why is that, @cchantep?

Comment: For the same reason it's generally preferable to used `Option.empty[T]` rather `null` for an optional data: type safety (which there allows Anorm to do appropriate data handling)

Comment: @cchantep Ah, so Anorm supports `Option` parameters directly?

Comment: The update doesn't use Anorm interpolation, being equivalent to `SQL(s"SELECT f($xInSql)")` and, not using the recommanded way of passing JDBC parameter with null value handle according the appropriate JDBC type. It's recommanded to first read the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#Working-with-optional/nullable-values

Comment: The first paragraph does. I specifically say that the way in the second parameter is not recommended.